# Missing file file android-support-v4.jar in my facebook sample code

Tags: android

I’m trying to get the facebook sample projects to code.  Right now all my inports that begin with

import android.support……..
have a error that says
“the android port android.support cannot be resolved.”

I compared the face book project to a project I made.  I found that my project had a folder called android dependencies and under that the file android-support-v4.jar. The facebook project did not have this.

I’m assuming this is why the face book projects are giving me the error.  How would I put the file android-support-v4.jar. into my face book projects?

Comment: Have you tried to click over you project then Android Tools > Add Support Library... ??

Answer (score 0):

Try the following options:

1. As mentioned in comments by @yugidroid, try right clicking on the project->android tools->fix project dependencies.
2. add manually through project's properties, library tabs, add external jar and point to support lib you have downloaded.
3. right click on project->android tools->download support lib